# Expo auto-fill OTP SMS in Application

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

How can I auto fill my OTP field with received message from 2FA provider? I see lots of apps doing a suggestion on iOS above the native keypad. This looks to me like a native thing that should work out of the box, but I cannot figure it out.

This screen:
[image]

I want that same suggestion for my application too, when the OTP field is focussed.

Developed in Expo, React-native.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but in case anyone else stumbles on this question; There are two prop types you can use in contemporary (0.68+) versions of React Native to achieve this:

```js
<TextInput
    ...
    autoComplete="sms-otp" // android
    textContentType="oneTimeCode" // ios
/>
```

You can use other prop options to provide the system context for which it will try and autocomplete fields, which can be reviewed [here (android)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/textinput#autocomplete-android) and [here (ios)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype-ios)